# Invisible script tag in HTML document with websockets code in it

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        Simple div
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I opened this HTML document in Chrome. Then in the debugger tool, I execute following

```
document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]
```

I got a script tag (which I never added in HTML) with a bunch of code like following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[  <-- For SVG support
    if ('WebSocket' in window) {
        (function() {
            function refreshCSS() {
                var sheets = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("link"));
                var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
                for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; ++i) {
                    var elem = sheets[i];
                    head.removeChild(elem);
                    var rel = elem.rel;
                    if (elem.href && typeof rel != "string" || rel.length == 0 || rel.toLowerCase() == "stylesheet") {
                        var url = elem.href.replace(/(&|\?)_cacheOverride=\d+/, '');
                        elem.href = url + (url.indexOf('?') >= 0 ? '&' : '?') + '_cacheOverride=' + (new Date().valueOf());
                    }
                    head.appendChild(elem);
                }
            }
            var protocol = window.location.protocol === 'http:' ? 'ws://' : 'wss://';
            var address = protocol + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + '/ws';
            var socket = new WebSocket(address);
            socket.onmessage = function(msg) {
                if (msg.data == 'reload') window.location.reload();
                else if (msg.data == 'refreshcss') refreshCSS();
            };
            if(sessionStorage && !sessionStorage.getItem('IsThisFirstTime_Log_From_LiveServer'))
            {
                console.log('Live reload enabled.');
                sessionStorage.setItem('IsThisFirstTime_Log_From_LiveServer', true);
            }
        })();
    }
    else {
        console.error('Upgrade your browser. This Browser is NOT supported WebSocket for Live-Reloading.');
    }
    // ]]>
</script>
```

Can anyone tell me what this is and why is it there?

Comment: It's probably coming from whatever server you're running.

Comment: It’s probably added by a live reload plugin installed in your browser

Comment: Are you using Brackets?

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I was running this from VS code live server. I stopped the server and opened the HTML document in browser, then then executing `document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]` returned nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's from vscode-live-server : 
https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server/blob/master/lib/live-server/injected.html

Answer (score 1):

obviously, you're using vscode-live-server and this script is related to that.
but it's not the primary problem, the problem is the global selector you use for the display property.

you have this rule in your CSS:
`* { display: block; }`

that includes the "title" in your "head" and the script the live-server is running.

you need to get rid of the global selector and the problem will be gone.
or maybe you can find a better solution to fix this while continuing to use live-server.